# NodeJs, Axios: Value of variable not updating with response from xhr request

Tags: node.js, http, axios, jsx, httpresponse

I am making an xhr request in nodejs using Axios. And I am trying to save a value from this response to a variable, but it isn't working and I am not sure why.

Code:

```
let redirectUrl = 'placeholder'
axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        redirectURL = res.url
        console.log(res.url, "HERE")
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      return res.render('index',{url: redirectURL})
```

I have tried declaring `redirectUrl` in both global as `var` and local scope, but the value isn't changing, on index when I console log this value, it logs `placeholder`. index is index.jsx as I am using jsx as the template engine.
Please let me know if I should provide any more information.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: If it returns “placeholder” are you sure that “res.url” does or is supposed to return anything besides the URL Requested? If the Response contains the URL then you should pluck it from the Data in the Response object. Correct me if I’m misunderstanding

Comment: When I console log res.url it logs the correct expected value. I did not understand what you mean by plucking from the response object though, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` is an async call, so your return will use the original (`placeholder`) value instead of the new one. Normally to solve this kind of asynchronicities  i use `async/await`

```
async function getRedirectURL(url) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    // Note that if you want some return value from axios call you access it by res.data
    console.log('res.url :', res.url, ". res.data:", res.data);
    return res.render('index',{url: res.data.url});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios is a promise-based HTTP client, So when javascript engine executes your code, it moves axios call to web API from callstack (line# 2) and then it starts to execute the last line return `res.render('index',{url: redirectURL})` where redirectURL value is **placeholder**. You have to write all the logic in promise then method, like

```
axios
  .get(url)
  .then((data) => res.render("index", { url: data.url }))
  .catch((err) => {
    // error response
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: I already tried this but it did not work, it keeps loading the page and doesn't render anything. But thank you, the answer was solved using @tam.teixeira 's solution